# Preprocessing data in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, pipeline, data-preprocessing

I have a simply sequential model written in Python using TensorFlow library. As an input I have categorical and numerical columns and in output I'm getting float number.

I would like deploy my model in Windows Application (.NET) and I am wondering how to deal with data encoders (eg. label encoder, normalization encoder).

I seem to have at least two options:

- save the encoders somehow - how?
- add preprocessing layer in tf (I am personally for this option), but how? I am looking for a solution analogous to FeatureUnion/ColumnTransform from sklearn. Is it possible to use a preprocessing layer with the option of setting an encoder for each column separately? How?

Answer (score 0):

Use sklearn preprocessing independently of the TensorFlow model in your training script. Afterward, save both your sklearn preprocessing steps and the TensorFlow model as [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/). Then, either feed the output of the preprocessing step as the input to the model in your .NET application or use the [ONNX helper](https://onnx.ai/onnx/api/helper.html) to stitch both models together in advance.

P.S.

If you need a concrete example how to combine several onnx models into one file, you could refer to [this](https://github.com/OKUA1/falcon/blob/main/falcon/serialization.py) file in my [Falcon-ML](https://github.com/OKUA1/falcon) library where I have exactly the same use case.